# Onchange show div, hide previous ones selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a script that selects stores from states and cities and show them in different divs. The problem I'm having is that when another city is selected, the previous div still show, but they should be hidden. Here's my script:

```
function showStores(state)
    {
        if (state == 'SS')
        {
            document.getElementById(document.getElementById('citySS').value).style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('citySS').selectedIndex = 0;    
        }

        else if (state == 'ZZ')
        {
            document.getElementById(document.getElementById('cityZZ').value).style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('cityZZ').selectedIndex = 0;    
        }
    }
        <form>
    <select onchange="javascript:showStores('SS');" id="citySS" name="citySS">
                <option selected>-</option>
                <option value="city1">city 1</option>
                <option value="city2">city 2</option>
    </select>

    <select onchange="javascript:showStores('ZZ');" id="cityZZ" name="cityZZ">
                <option selected>-</OPTION>
                <option value="city3">city 3</option>
                <option value="city4">city 4</option>

    </select>           
    </form>

    <div id="city1" style="display: none">
    content 1
    </div>

    <div id="city2" style="display: none">
    content 2
    </div>

    <div id="city3" style="display: none">
    content 3
    </div>

    <div id="city4" style="display: none">
    content 4
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6h9mLw6f

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)  it might help you

Comment: You could add a class to the divs and hide them using `document.getElementsByClassname()` (returns an array, you need to iterate over it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every div you wish to show/hide, you can assign a class attribute like so:

```html
<div class="cityClass" id="city1" style="display: none">
```

Next, in your JavaScript, whenever the `showStores()` function is called, you should find all the divs that belong to the class `cityClass` and make sure they are hidden. This is done by first finding all these divs:

```js
var allCities = document.getElementsByClassName("cityClass");
```

And going over the array to hide them one by one:

```js
for (var i=0; i < allCities.length; i++)
{
    allCities[i].setAttribute('style','display: none');
}
```